# enable user left click on the items of gridview but disable right click and select an item in xaml

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

```
<GridView
                                    Grid.Row="1" 
                                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceOrderList}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ServiceOrderListItemTemplate}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServiceOrder, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsSwipeEnabled="false">
                                    <winRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <behaviors:EventToBoundCommandBehavior
                                            Command="{Binding ServiceOrderItemClickCommand}"
                                            Event="Tapped" />
                                    </winRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                </GridView>
```

I want use to be able to do a left click on the items of gridview but dosn't want to allow them to right click and select an item, please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the items to be selectable at all, set `SelectionMode="None"` and `IsItemClickEnabled="True"` along with setting an `ItemClick` event.

If you want them to be selectable, but only left click, you can set `IsRightClickEnabled="False"`.

Comment: i dont have property called IsRightClickEnabled, i do have  IsRightTapEnabled property but setting it to false dosn't help

Comment: That is the one, RightTap. So, you do want them to be selectable, but only with left click?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is put `RightTapped` event in your `GridView.ItemTemplate` which is implement : `e.Handled = true`

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="30,10"
                              Width="350" Tapped="Grid_Tapped_1" RightTapped="Grid_RightTapped">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Height="40" Source="{Binding Path=Image}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-3,11,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Foreground="#232323" Text="{Binding Path=RoomTypeString}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Path=RoomCountString}"
                                        Foreground="#232323" FontFamily="Segoe WP"
                                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```